# How to solve the wave velocity in steel

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, solidmechanics, wave-propagation

In the simulation of stress wave propagation, I have the following two problems.

**First question:**

This question comes from page 69 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006587578&d=4FAFDAC3B4A8FB0CA9FD9A777D275E95&fenlei=13020432).

The Lame equation for a linear elastic body without volume force is as follows:

[image]

```
Grad[Div[u[x, t], {x, t}], {x, t}] + μ*
   Laplacian[u[x, t], {x, t}] == ρ*D[u[x, t], {t, 2}]
```

The relationship between the parameters `λ` and `μ`, Young's modulus `E` and Poisson's ratio `ν` in the above figure are shown as follows:

[image]

If the material is steel, then $E = 2.10*10^5MPa$, $ν = 0.28$, $ρ = 0.01 g/mm^3$. Assuming that the stress wave is an irrotational wave, how to calculate the velocity of the wave propagating in the steel.

**Second question:**

I saw the propagation animation of Rayleigh wave [here](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/18/built-to-last-understanding-earthquake-engineering/), but the post only provided CDF file at the end of the post. I want to make this animation with MMA. How can I get the same effect as in the animation.

[image]

Comment: There should be nothing that prevents you from tearing a CDF apart to use the underlying code, at least from my understanding/limited experience.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you very much for your reply, but I don't know how to extract the relevant code from the CDF file. Could you give me a post about how to extract the code?

Comment: I’ll see what I can muster :) it may be several hours from now, but I’ll try to show you what I mean

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 Are looking for some code generating numerical solution of the elastic wave propagation like this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524928/example-of-an-elastic-transverse-wave/524990#524990 ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Your answer is great, can you share the code you used in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/524990/252335)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To visualize 3D elastic P-,R-,S-wave we use standard 2D FEM solver (see tutorial) and `ListPointPlot3D[]`. This code generates S-wave:

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; \[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {x, y}]; 
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.03]; 
mesh["Wireframe"];
diffusionCoefficients = "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-(Y/(1 - \[Nu]^2)), 0}, {0, -((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/(2*(1 - \[Nu]^2)))}}, {{0, -((Y*\[Nu])/(1 - \[Nu]^2))}, {-((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/(2*(1 - \[Nu]^2))), 0}}}, {{{0, -((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/(2*(1 - \[Nu]^2)))}, {-((Y*\[Nu])/(1 - \[Nu]^2)), 0}}, 
       {{-((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/(2*(1 - \[Nu]^2))), 0}, {0, -(Y/(1 - \[Nu]^2))}}}} /. {Y -> 10^2, \[Nu] -> 33/100}; massCoefficients = "MassCoefficients" -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}; 
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"Time", "DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {t, {u, v}, {x, y}}]; 
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Time", "Space"} -> {0., ToNumericalRegion[mesh]}];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
loadCoefficients = "LoadCoefficients" -> {{0}, {0}};
    Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Nv] = NeumannValue[0., y == 1]; Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Du] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]; Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Nu] = NeumannValue[0, x == 5]; 
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Dv] = DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0.05*Sin[Pi*(x + t)], y == 0 || y == 1]; 


initCoeffs = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, {diffusionCoefficients, massCoefficients, loadCoefficients}];
initBCs = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {{Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Du], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Nu]}, {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Dv], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], Nv]}}];
sdpde = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd, "Stationary"];
sbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd, "Stationary"];
rhs[t_?NumericQ, uv_, duv_] := Module[{l, s, d, m, tdpde, tbcs, rayleighDamping},
  NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[sd, "Time", t];
  {l, s, d, m} = sdpde["SystemMatrices"];
  tdpde = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd, "Transient"];
  tbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd, "Transient"];
  {l, s, d, m} += tdpde["SystemMatrices"];
  rayleighDamping = 0.1*m + 0.04*s;
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s, rayleighDamping, m}, tbcs];
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s, rayleighDamping, m}, sbcs];
  l - s.uv - rayleighDamping.duv
  ]
dof = methodData["DegreesOfFreedom"];
init = dinit = ConstantArray[0, {dof, 1}];
mass = sdpde["MassMatrix"];
stiff = sdpde["StiffnessMatrix"];
rd = 0.1*mass + 0.04*stiff;
sparsity = ArrayFlatten[{{mass["PatternArray"], mass["PatternArray"]}, {rd["PatternArray"], rd["PatternArray"]}}];
Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]];

tfun = NDSolveValue[{
    mass.uv''[ t] == rhs[t, uv[t], uv'[t]]
    , uv[ 0] == init, uv'[ 0] == dinit}, uv, {t, 0, 8}
   , Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
   , Jacobian -> {Automatic, Sparse -> sparsity}
   , EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)
   ];
split = Span @@@ Transpose[{Most[# + 1], Rest[#]} &[methodData["IncidentOffsets"]]];
```

Visualization

```
Do[mesht = Function[t,
     dmesh = 
      ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, Part[tfun[t], #] & /@ split, 
       "ScalingFactor" -> 2]] /@ {k}; 
  c3D = Table[{dmesh["Coordinates"][[i, 1]], j/6, 
     dmesh["Coordinates"][[i, 2]]}, {i, 
     Length[dmesh["Coordinates"]]}, {j, 0, 6}]; 
  frame3D[k] = 
   ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[c3D, 1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];, {k, 4, 8,
    1/10}];
```

To save picture as a gif file we use

```
Export["C:\\...\\waveS3D.gif", 
 Table[frame3D[k], {k, 4, 8, 1/10}], AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I ran the second piece of code(`Do[mesht = Function[...1/10}];`), the program output some error messages (version 12.1).

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 Sorry, it should be ` "ScalingFactor" -> 2`. Code been updated.